# Get feature names for dataframe.corr

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I am using the cancer data set from sklearn and I need to find the correlations between features. I am able to find the correlated columns, but I am not able to present them in a "nice" way, so that they will be an input for Dataframe.drop.
Here is my code:

```
cancer_data = load_breast_cancer()
df=pd.DataFrame(cancer_data.data, columns=cancer_data.feature_names)
corr = df.corr()
#filter to find correlations above 0.6
corr_triu = corr.where(~pd.np.tril(pd.np.ones(corr.shape)).astype(pd.np.bool))
corr_triu = corr_triu.stack()
corr_result = corr_triu[corr_triu > 0.6]
print(corr_result)
df.drop(columns=[?])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want the columns that correlate with some other column in the dataset, ie drop columns that don't appear in `corr_result`. So you'll want to get the unique variables from the index of `corr_result`, from each level. There may be repeats so take care of that as well, such as with sets:

```
corr_result.index = corr_result.index.remove_unused_levels()
corr_vars = set()
corr_vars.update(corr_result.index.unique(level=0))
corr_vars.update(corr_result.index.unique(level=1))
all_vars = set(df.columns)
df.drop(columns=all_vars - corr_vars)
```

Comment: I am a little confused now... My first impression was that I need to remove the one set of columns that appear in the corr_result, as they are correlated with some other, so I don't need them when training the data set. May I wrong?

Comment: The two index levels in `corr_result` represent the two variables you are calculating the correlation with. What you did with `corr` is a pairwise calculation of  correlation of all columns in `df`. So for a particular row, you are taking the correlation of those two variables and the number in the dataset is the correlation coefficient.